Prove by induction that $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ if $a_n=\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $x^2-x-1=0$
If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $x^2-x-1=0$, $\alpha>\beta$ and $a_m=\frac{\alpha^m-\beta^m}{\alpha-\beta}$. I am trying to prove, by induction, that $a_k=a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}$ for $k\ge 2$.
I already have the base case by noting that $a_0=0,a_1=1$, and $a_2=\alpha+\beta$, but $\alpha+\beta=1$ from the properties of the quadratic.
Now assuming $P(n)$ being the statement that $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ is true, I am unable to prove that $P(n+1)$ is also true.
What I tried so far is as follows.

$a_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha^{n+1}-\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta}=\frac{\alpha^{n+1}}{\alpha}\cdot\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ where $x=\beta/\alpha$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=\alpha^n(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n)$ (Sum of GP.)
$\implies a_{n+1}=\alpha^n(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{n-1})+\alpha^nx^n$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=\alpha^n\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}+\alpha^nx^n$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{1-x}+\alpha^nx^n$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=\alpha\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}+\alpha^nx^n$.
Now, I will use the fact that $\alpha^2-\alpha-1=0$ which means $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$ which further means that $\alpha=1+1/\alpha$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}+\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha(\alpha-\beta)}+\alpha^nx^n$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{a_n}{\alpha}+\alpha^nx^n$.

This is where I am stuck. I do realise that I haven't used the inductive hypothesis yet. Since I want to keep $a_n$, and transform the rest ($a_n/\alpha+\alpha^nx^n$) to $a_{n-1}$, I did try to use the inductive hypothesis there to convert this term into $$\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}}{\alpha}+\alpha^nx^n.$$ But I don't know how to proceed any further from here.
Edit:

$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha(\alpha-\beta)}+\beta^n$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{\alpha^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}-\frac{\beta^n-\beta^n(\alpha^2-\alpha\beta)}{\alpha(\alpha-\beta)}$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{\alpha^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}-\frac{\beta^n-\beta^n(\alpha^2-(-1)}{\alpha(\alpha-\beta)}$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{\alpha^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}-\frac{\beta^n-\beta^n(\alpha^2+1)}{\alpha(\alpha-\beta)}$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{\alpha^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}-\frac{\beta^n-\beta^n\alpha^2-\beta^n)}{\alpha(\alpha-\beta)}$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{\alpha^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}-\frac{-\beta^n\alpha^2}{\alpha(\alpha-\beta)}$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{\alpha^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}-\frac{-\beta^n\alpha}{\alpha-\beta}$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{\alpha^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}-\frac{-\beta^{n-1}(\alpha\beta)}{\alpha-\beta}$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{\alpha^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}-\frac{-\beta^{n-1}(-1)}{\alpha-\beta}$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{\alpha^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}-\frac{\beta^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{\alpha^{n-1}-\beta^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}$.
$\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$.

Edit: As suggest, I looked at Recurrence formula for sequence - Apostol's Analysis, but it doesn't answer my query. The distinction is that I am looking for a solution using induction (or its variants) only.

I might be inclined to abstract it father.  Prove $a_n = \lambda_\alpha \alpha^n + \lambda_\beta \beta^n$.

This question is similar to: Recursion formula for sequence - Apostol's Analysis. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search. Note that there are ...

(cont.) quite a few somewhat related questions involving the Fibonacci sequence, such as [How to show that closed form of Fibonacci number is roots ratio difference of $n^{th}$ power of roots to difference of roots of $x^2 - x - 1=0$](/q/261359.

@JohnOmielan /q/261359 does not address my question even though they look related. I am looking for a solution using induction, and no other way.

Instead of the usual induction, try apply strong form of mathematical induction. Because you only assume $P(n)$ is true which is not enough, you can see it later.
Base case: Instead of one base case, you will need two, that is $P(k)$ for $k=1,2$.
Hypothesis: Assume $P(k)$ is true for $k=n-1,n$.
Want to show $P(n+1)$ is true.
You can substitute $a_{n}$ and $a_{n-1}$, then show that $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$ indeed follows the statement.
$$\begin{align}
a_{n+1}&=a_n+a_{n-1}\\
&=\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}+\frac{\alpha^{n-1}-\beta^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}\\
&=\frac{1}{\alpha-\beta}(\alpha^{n-1}(1+\alpha)-\beta^{n-1}(1+\beta))\\
&=\frac{1}{\alpha-\beta}(\alpha^{n-1}\cdot\alpha^2-\beta^{n-1}\cdot\beta^2)\\
&=\frac{\alpha^{n+1}-\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta}
\end{align}$$
QED.
Note: you can learn the strong from of induction from here.
Plus, $1+x=x^2$ where $x$ is solution to the quadratic you mention. This is important in the proof.

But the inductive hypothesis that $P(k)$ is true for $k=1,\dotsc,n$ was never used. With this solution, $n$ is not confined to be in ${2,3,\ldots}$. Which might not be such a bad thing, I realize.

The case when $k=n-1$ is used, that is $a_{n-1}=\frac{\alpha^{n-1}-\beta^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}$ is assumed to be true in the hypothesis.

@MridulGupta Actually, you can just assume $P(n)$ and $P(n-1)$ to be true. That is sufficient to prove $P(n+1)$.

$a_{n-1}=\frac{\alpha^{n-1}-\beta^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}$ is a given. I think the indices might be confusing here.

Your hypothesis only assume $P(n)$ is true, not $P(n-1)$. However $P(n+1)$ depends both on $P(n)$ and $P(n-1)$. That is all I can explain.

A website said "Strong induction is useful when a simple proof that the predicate holds for  $n+1$ does not follow just from the fact that it holds at $n$, but from the fact that it holds for other values  $\leq n$ ."

The thing to keep in mind with strong induction is that as you induction step involves not just $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ but $P(k-1),P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ you must do two bases cases for $k=1; k=2$

As $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$, by using the relation between coefficients and roots of a polynomial (or Vieta' formulas), we have:
$$
\alpha + \beta = 1 \quad\quad \alpha \cdot \beta = -1
$$
Next, rewrite the both sides of expression of $a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$, like this:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{LHS} &=  \frac{1}{\alpha - \beta}\left(\alpha^n - \beta^n\right) \\
\text{RHS} &=  \frac{1}{\alpha - \beta}\left(
\alpha^{n-1} - \beta^{n-1} + \alpha^{n-2} - \beta^{n-2}
\right) \\
\end{aligned}
$$
By using the relation of Vieta' formulas, we can continually rewrite the RHS as below:
$$
\begin{aligned} 
\text{RHS} &=  \frac{1}{\alpha - \beta}\left(
\alpha^{n-1}\left( 1 + \alpha^{-1} \right)- \beta^{n-1}\left( 1 + \beta^{-1} \right) \right)\\
& = \frac{1}{\alpha - \beta}\left(
\alpha^{n-1}\left( 1 - \beta \right)- \beta^{n-1}\left( 1 - \alpha \right) \right) \\
& = \frac{1}{\alpha - \beta}\left(
\alpha^{n} - \beta^{n}  \right) \\
& = \text{LHS}
\end{aligned}
$$
Q.E.D.

Assume by induction that $a_i=\frac{\alpha^i-\beta^i}{\alpha-\beta}$ for all $i\le n$. Now,
$$a_{n-1}+a_n=\frac{\alpha^n+\alpha^{n-1}-\beta^n-\beta^{n-1}}{\alpha-\beta}$$
Can you show that the RHS is $a_{n+1}$?
